# Version History in SharePoint 2010 Discussion lists

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a **SharePoint 2010 Discussion list** in which I have enabled versioning. Each of the discussion list items have replies which behave like child items. 
I am saving the list items to SharePoint discussion list using C#. I am able to view version history of child and parent items when updating through SharePoint UI. However when I am saving through my code, **the versioning doesn't work for replies** or the child items.

Comment: For users to be able to help, you may want to include the code you have trouble with and any errors it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you use **SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion** method or **SPListItem.SystemUpdate** method to update the list item.

**UPDATE()**

Updates the item in the database.

Updates the build-in columns "Modified" and "Modified by" values.

Creates a new version

**SYSTEMUPDATE() ARE THE SAME SYSTEMUPDATE(FALSE)**

Updates the item in the database.

No changes in the "Modified" and "Modified By" fields.

No new version created

Triggers the item events.

**SYSTEMUPDATE(TRUE)**

Updates the item in the database.

No changes in the "Modified" and "Modified By" fields.

new version created

Triggers the item events.

**UPDATEOVERWRITEVERSION()**

Updates the item but does not create a new version.

Updates the "Modified" and "Modified by" values.

Note that : You can also disable the triggering of events by using "this.EventFiringEnabled = false;". Do your update and enable the events again with "this.EventFiringEnabled = true;".

Comment: Thanks @LZ_MSFT  I was able to figure it out. It's similar to the answer you have suggested. I have been updating the replies through my code but SPListItem.Update() was missing. I have added this and voila it's working.